# I can't figure out how to populate a List<string> inside a c# Task correctly

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I wrote this absurd code just to get some clarity:

- Does it make a difference if I use `CallingFunctionAsync_v1` versus `CallingFunctionAsync_v2`?

If so, can someone explain why?

Definitions:

```
class WorkHorse
{
    const int RECORD_SIZE = 12;

    public async Task<List<string>> DoTheThingAsync_v1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        List<string> theList = new List<string>();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[RECORD_SIZE];

        using var fs = File.OpenRead("awesome_stuff.bin");
        int read;
        while ((read = await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, RECORD_SIZE, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            theList.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, RECORD_SIZE));
        }

        return theList;
    }

    public async Task DoTheThingAsync_v2(List<string> theList, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[RECORD_SIZE];

        using var fs = File.OpenRead("awesome_stuff.bin");
        int read;
        while ((read = await fs.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, RECORD_SIZE, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)) != 0)
        {
            theList.Add(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, RECORD_SIZE));
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class FunTimes
{
    List<string> TheStrings;

    public async Task CallingFunctionAsync_v1(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.TheStrings = await new WorkHorse().DoTheThingAsync_v1(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public Task CallingFunctionAsync_v2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        this.TheStrings = new List<string>();
        return new WorkHorse().DoTheThingAsync_v2(this.TheStrings, cancellationToken);
    }

}
```

Comment: If an exception occurs somewhere during execution of the methods the `v1` will not have a result but `v2` can already have some items added to the list that was provided (incomplete). But the difference between these 2 has nothing to do with `async` and `Task` as far as I can see.

Comment: v2 has another avenue for a thread safety problem (depending on how its implemented), in this case not so much (all disregarding the fact AsyncRead will be synchronous anyway)

Comment: Just make it a Task<IList..>, and return the result..? The more side-effects that can be avoided.. in both cases, use local variables instead of properties to avoid potentially external state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V1 is the better approach.  It is a pure, blackbox function, which always returns a new list.

V2 expects an initialized instance of `List<string>`, which is error-prone.  You can easily pass null and have an issue.  Then, since these are async methods, you can run V2 concurrently and you will have race conditions over the list you have passed.